# Backbone.js updating a Collection's model in the collection

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections

I am having a bit of trouble organising the JSON I pass in into Backbone models as months (I am getting an empty collection). I am trying to be explicit as possible so the Year Collection is actually setting each of its parameters like so.

So I have a Backbone collection called `Year` which is a collection of Backbone models `Month` which in turn has an events attribute which is a collection of the model `Event`.

```
$(function(){
var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Event
});

var Month = Backbone.Model.extend ({
});

var Year = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Month,
    url: '/api/v1/calendar/2014'

});

window.Calendar = new Year();
var promise = Calendar.fetch();

promise.done(function(response){ 
    if ('events' in response) {
        console.log('Events found');
        response = response.events;

        // Cycle through events and add to Collection
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var currentMonth = response[i].startdate.split('-');

            thisEvent = new Event(response[i]);
            thisMonth = new Month({
                'name': currentMonth[1],
                'events': new Events(thisEvent)
            });

            Calendar.add(thisMonth);                  
            console.log('Set ' + currentMonth[1] + ' with Event ' + response[i]);

        }

    } else {
        console.error('Zero events');
    }
}).fail(function(response){ 
    console.error('Failed to fetch Calendar');
}); 
});
```

The JSON I pass in is very simple, something like this

```
{
"status": "success",
"year": 2014,
"events": [
    {
        "title": "None",
        "startdate": "2014-01-23",
        "description": "Event Description"
    },
    {
        "title": "None",
        "startdate": "2014-01-25",
        "description": "Event Description 2"
    }
]
}
```

I am not quite sure why I get an empty collection. The thing I am least certain about is setting the `Month` model with `new Events(response[i])`. Ideally I would initialize the `events` key with a `new Events` and then add `response[i]` to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Use promise when fetching

Comment: Would that mean fetching on initialized?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the section `// Cycle through events and add to Collection`. Is this just a mockup of your code, or are you actually going with this implementation, where you instantiate `thisEvent` and `thisMonth` on every iteration? I didn't understand your last question about getting an array you didn't expect. Did you mean the server response (your JSON object) isn't coming in as expected, or is your `for loop` generating unexpected arrays. If you'r referring to your `for loop`...well, you're not modifying any arrays(!). I can help if you provide some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way usually:

```
var promise = calendar.fetch(); 

promise.done(function(response){ 
    //This is where you process the collection that is returned from the server. 
}).fail(function(response){ 
    //In case of failure 
});
```

Comment: Great thanks! I am still having trouble creating the correct model structure. I've updated the code as it currently stands. Could you take a look at the section with `// Cycle through events and add to Collection`. As far as I can tell this should work fine but I end up with an array longer than I expected without the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do here is override the Collections parse function and do something like this:

```
  parse: function(response) {
    this.status = response.status;
    this.year = response.year;
    return response.events;
  }
```

parse function should always return an array from which collection is populated.
Hope this helps.